# why fit-content() doesn't work on grid-template-rows property in Css-Grid but works well on grid-template-columns?

Tags: html, css, grid

I'll give  one example, where have two images. size of them is 168px-width and 180-height. I only allowed to use up to 300px height, but it renders the target two images vertically, which is not the case with grid-template-columns, where everything works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HAYTI</title>
  <style>
   
.grid {
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid black;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(300px) 100px ;
  height: 600px;


  background: orange;
  
}

.itemm {
border: 2px solid black;
}

.item1 {
font-size: 20px;
 background: lime;
 padding: 5px;

}

.item2 {
  background: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
  
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   
<section class="grid">
  <div class="itemm item1"><img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/28qba.jpg"> <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/28qba.jpg"></div>
  <div class="itemm item2">item2</div>
  <div class="itemm item2">item3</div>
  <div class="itemm item2">item3</div>
</section>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not using 300px? fit-content() can give bigger values than what is inside it --> *The fit-content() CSS function clamps a given size to an available size according to the formula min(maximum size, max(minimum size, argument)).*

Comment: for example if it is...
grid-template-rows: min(400px, max(180px, 300px));
then the formula will take 300px, this works for grid-template-columns but it doesn't work for grid-template-rows.

another example....
grid-template-rows: min(400px(max-content), max(180px, 500px));
in this example formula will take 400px;
if is 400px, so what is the point of using fit-content if we can just write
grid-template-rows: max-content; ?

thank you